# Problems moving Django App to Production

Tags: python, django, apache, solr, django-haystack

I've run into two problems when moving my Django app from the dev server to a production one (Apache). I'm assuming both may have something to do with my Apache configuration. Any help would be great.

(1) I'm using the jQuery-based Elfinder filebrowser with yawd-elfinder connector. On the dev server I can browse files with chinese characters just fine, but on the Apache server Elfinder gives me an error:

> Unable to open "Folder_Name". ascii File_name_with_chinese_
>   characters.doc ordinal not in range(128)

I made sure the Apache config has the UTF-8 CharacterSet selected. A post [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mezzanine-users/ud0e9Mo1WSE) says something similar may be caused by a Locale issue... but I'm not really sure how to approach that type of problem. Any ideas/suggestions? (You'll see a reference in there to yawd-elfinder specifically... my version has that patch)

(2) I'm using Haystack + Solr for search capability. Search only works if I change 127.0.0.1 to the machine's IP.

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.solr_backend.SolrEngine',
    'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/test_core_django2'
},
```

On the dev server it was fine as 127.0.0.1. This one isn't as big an issue as I found a workaround, but it's a bit confusing for me

Comment: 1. ssh into your terminal and run `locale`
2. run django shell in your terminal `./manage.py shell`
then run 
`import locale`
`locale.getlocale()`
`locale.getdefaultlocale()`

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right track!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody else runs into the same problem, I found that Apache was overriding the locale settings. Thanks to luke_aus above, I printed out locale settings on both Apache and dev... the Apache/mod_wsgi instance output as ascii.

This link covers how to fix it:

http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/09/setting-lang-and-lcall-when-using.html

Specifically:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess my-django-site lang='en_US.UTF-8' locale='en_US.UTF-8'
```

Note that this only works if you are running wsgi in Daemon mode.

Comment: Apache wasn't overriding them. It is simply that Apache doesn't set any. Thus you would have inherited whatever the default is for the operating system if nothing is set, which is generally ASCII.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, and the article itself! What exactly does the AddDefaultCharSet Directive do? I had UTF-8 here by default and thought it would cover the issue I was having.

Comment: The AddDefaultCharSet directive relates to static file responses returned by Apache itself. Nothing to do with the locale environment of code running under mod_wsgi.